# How to change project name in `go.mod` and import statements project wide in golang?

Tags: go

I was working on a template go project to be able to quick start my go projects. Needed an easy way to be able to change the `go.mod` file and all subsequent import statements to reflect the new project name

Note: I already have a solution, not sure if it's the best one. Wanted to know if there are other approaches to achieve this.

Comment: Please post your existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple shell script to achieve this.

```
#! /bin/sh
echo -n "Enter new go package name: "
read pkg_name

# update go mod
go mod edit -module $pkg_name

escaped_pkg_name=$(echo $pkg_name | sed 's/\//\\\//g')

# fix imports project wide, replaces .../go-start with escaped pkg_name
find . -name "*.go" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -s "s/github.com\/cijin\/go-start/${escaped_pkg_name}/g"
```